# How can I add a border to neovim command completion menu?

Tags: neovim, wildmenu

I've been configuring my Neovim for quite a while now. This command menu seems a little ugly with the transparent background. I'd be great if I could add a border for this menu. How can I do that ?

[image]

I'll accept both `lua` and `vim-lang` answers.

Comment: You cannot add a border but you _can_ make it opaque: `:set pumblend =0`. In Vim, it shouldn't be transparent as there is no option to make it transparent, so you should remove the mention of vim from your question title.

Comment: I previously tried something like `vim.cmd[[:highlight Pmenu guibg=NONE cterm=NONE term=NONE]]` to make my `cmp` completion menus transparent. Can I have different highlights for the cmp completion menu and this completion menu ?

Comment: No. Both those menus use the same highlight group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose you to use the [wilder plugin](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim)

With the following settings:

```
call wilder#set_option('renderer', wilder#popupmenu_renderer(wilder#popupmenu_border_theme({
      \ 'highlights': {
      \   'border': 'Normal',
      \ },
      \ 'border': 'single',
      \ })))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Lua implementation of what @Vivian De Smedt mentioned.

```lua
local status_ok, wilder = pcall(require, "wilder")
if not status_ok then
  print("wilder plugin not found")
  return
end

wilder.set_option('renderer', wilder.popupmenu_renderer(
  wilder.popupmenu_border_theme({
    highlights = { border = 'Normal' },
    border = 'single',
  })
))

wilder.setup({modes = {':', '/', '?'}})
```

**Another way:**

If you use `nvim-cmp` for auto-completion like me, you can apply cmp popup menu borders to the command-line using [cmp-cmdline](https://github.com/hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline) plugin. This plugin will also let you fuzzy find the options.

```lua
local cmp_status_ok, cmp = pcall(require, "cmp")
if not cmp_status_ok then
  return
end

cmp.setup({

  -- .... (other setups)

  -- Add borders around the popup window
  window = {
    completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),  
  },

})

-- Enable command-line completion 
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
  sources = {
    { name = 'cmdline' },
  },
  formatting = {
    fields = { "abbr" },
  }
})
```